# Migrating from Trinity to Firefly - PIN requested which I never created

Tags: firefly, migration

I am somewhat late to the migration process. I checked my Trinity wallet and saw a zero balance. I then did the snapshot thing and then saw that all of my balance had been subtracted. I installed Firefly after I realized it is the upgraded wallet. However, when I go to sign in, Firefly is requesting a PIN, which I never created. I only have the original seed.

Is there a way to log in with the seed?
Have I lost all the funds?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Trinity showed an outgoing transation? If you did not migrate your funds and nobody else did, there should not be an outgoing transaction in Trinity.

If you are asked for a PIN in Firefly, click the "Close profile" link on top, and create a new one. For type of profile select "Migrate or restore wallet", then "I have an 81-character seed". The rest should be self explanatory.

Make sure to write down your new recovery phrase where you had stored the seed, as after the migration your old seed will be indeed empty and worthless.